# (Numerical) Integration in log space

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, logarithms, transformation

I have some function $f(x)$, which I'd like to integrate to find, $F(r) = \int_r^\infty f(x) dx $.  Is there a way to do this using the values parametrized in log-space?  I.e. some function $G(r, \log[F(x)], \log x) = F(r)$?

For numerical reasons, I only have the two arrays, $X_i = \log x_i$, and $Y_i = \log[ f(x_i) ]$.  Obviously, converting to $f_i$ and $x_i$ would be possible, but would introduce significant numerical issues.

Comment: Well, one question is: how much do the $Y_i$ vary? If they vary by a lot, is there anywhere that they are much larger? (Your problem can be recast as an exponential integral, and there are asymptotic approximations for exponential integrals, see Laplace's method).

Comment: @Ian, $Y_I$ is monotonically decreasing, and does vary over many orders of magnitude.  I do not know the derivatives, $f'(x)$,  but of course I could approximate them...